# SSRS 2008 - returning a date 3 months from today from a list of dates

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Report Item that contains dates, that I want to compare against today's date, if it's within 3 months or today then either return that date or return a 'Yes'.

Is there a simple way of carrying this out?

Comment: Have a search for SQL `dateadd` and `datediff`

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateDiff` to Get the difference Between two dates

```
IF DATEDIFF( MONTH,@ReportDate, Getdate())<=3 
BEGIN
     SELECT @ReportDate as ReportDate 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN
     SELECT "Yes" 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method you can use in your query:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2018-08-01'

SELECT CASE WHEN DATEADD(MONTH,3,GETDATE()) >= @Date 
        THEN CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR) ELSE 'Yes' 
        END AS ColumnName
```

SSRS expression might look something like this:

```
=IIF("2018-05-01" > DATEADD(DateInterval.Month, 3, Today), "Yes", Today)
```

Where you would obviously replace `2018-05-01` with your date field.